# Notify the parent pane about the mouse click event

Tags: events, javafx, javafx-2, mouseevent

I have list of stackPanes on which different fxmls are loaded. So i want to know which of the stackPane is in interactive with user. For example, if a event occurs on a fxml, then stackPane should be notified abt this event. I added mouse click event to the stackPane, but its not triggering everytime.

```
stackPane.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event ){
                setSelectedPane( (Pane) event.getSource() );
            }
        } );
```

Comment: I do not understand your requirement. Do you swap between the StackPanes? Or do you want to know which layout is  currently sitting on the top of all other Layouts in one particular StackPane?

Comment: For example, there are five stackPanes, each stackPane has its own fxml loaded on to it. If an event occurs in any of fxml files, then stackPane should be notified that an event occured in its fxml.

Comment: Are we concerned about just notifying or do you want the Parent loaded from fxml to be transparent to MouseEvents and all of them should be delegated to the StackPane?

Comment: concerned about just notifying,

Comment: Try filter stackPane.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){}; instead.

Comment: @Hareesh All events delegate to the parents. For example, if you have a `mouse click event listener` on the StackPane and to its top most child, both of the listeners will be executed. So, the parent will always be notified of the event.

Comment: its not happening, I added mouse event handler for stackPane but its not getting called, whenever a mouse events occurs on the child classes.

Comment: It should work, can you add a MCVE which shows the issue you are facing? Here is a [small example](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/66322bc3a998bae23e56), which proves my point.

Comment: I added EventFilter as suggested by @Uluk Biy. And then it worked fine.

Comment: thanks Uluk and Itachi